# Extract article's headline from HTML(using Boilerpipe)

Tags: java, html, html-content-extraction, boilerpipe

Boilerpipe allows to extract just the article's text from webpage, cleaning up all the HTML mess. However, how could I extract article's headline? There is a a way to just use page's title, but it is sometimes incorrect and contains unneeded words(e.g. "title - sitename").

Another idea is to find text between `<h1>` and `</h1>`, but I still thought I would ask some more solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing a web crawler? I think the difficulty is that you need to know where the title is in a whole html.
For most website they have a unique pattern for writing html, it should be known before the crawler being written.

Comment: Yeah, kinda, only the headline extraction part is needed

Comment: So the structure of html is very important. Hence websites have different structures. It's certainly a time exhausting work...